# How to get list of all azure blob containers of all regions and how to get Region of a Azure blob container

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-java-sdk

I need help with two questions using java sdk:

> 1. How to get a list of all Azure blob containers in all regions with their region name/ code?

Do I need to loop over all the Storage accounts to get a list of Blob containers?

> 2. How to get region Code of an azure account from a `blobServiceClient` or `BlobContainerClient` or `BlobContainerItem`?

As far as I know azure does not have regions of a container but regions are associated with `Storage account` (correct me if I am wrong). 
How to get Region of a `storage account` from `blobServiceClient`.

I can get account Info using

```
blobServiceClient.getAccountInfo()
```

but it does not have any region information in it.

**Note**

I have `storage account key` with which I generate `connection string` with which I get the `blobServiceClient`, but there is no way of getting region of that storage account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For infomation/operation on storage account resource (instead of container, blob etc. under storage account), you could use a management client, as [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/storage-java-manage-storage-accounts/getting-started-with-storage---manage-storage-account---in-java/).

Related code [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-java-manage-storage-accounts/blob/master/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/management/storage/samples/ManageStorageAccount.java#L123-L129). Basically list all storage accounts (by subscription or by resource group), then check its region() method.